# Как поменять реакцию на нажатие кнопки DeleteButton у TextBox?

Tags: c#, uwp

У меня на фрейме имеется пара `TextBox`, я поменял их стиль так, что бы их `DeleteButton` были видны всегда. Однако эти боксы не реагируют на нажатие, если у них свойство `IsReadOnly` равно `true`. Я назначил новый обработчик нажатия, но теперь мне нужно определить, у какого `TextBox` нажата кнопка очищения. Так вот, как определить родителя кнопки в этом событии?

**Обновление, я не то вставил.**

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //var parent = ((Button) sender).Parent;?            
}
```

Кусочек из стиля `TextBox`:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
     Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
     IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
     MinWidth="34" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
     Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
```

Comment: По идее, если этот обработчик подписан на события каждого TextBox, то объект(конкретный TextBox), который возбудил событие находится в sender.

Comment: @ iluxa1810, простите, я случайно не то вставил. Сейчас исправил.

Comment: Код подписки этого обработчика тоже не помешал бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное, так:

```
DependencyObject o = (DependencyObject)sender;
while (!(o is TextBox))
    o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)o;
```

Пояснение: у вас в визуальном дереве `TextBox` является предком `Button`'а. Функция [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent) возвращает вам непосредственного предка, и вам придётся «прошагать» вверх несколько уровней до тех пор, пока вы не попадёте на `TextBox`.

Если вы хотите защитить ваш код от возможных ошибок, имеет смысл проверять, не упёрлись ли вы в корневой элемент, если по каким-то причинам вы не внутри `TextBox`'а:

```
DependencyObject o = (DependencyObject)sender;
while (o != null && !(o is TextBox))
    o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
if (o == null)
{
    // вы не внутри TextBox'а, что делаем?
}
else
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)o;
    // всё хорошо, работаем
}
```

---

Ещё вариант: в разметке положить нужный элемент в `Tag`:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton" ...
        Click="DeleteButton_Click"
        Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

и в code-behind

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)button.Tag;
```

Опять-таки, если есть сомнения, можно сделать больше проверок в коде:

```
TextBox textBox = (sender as RichTextBlock)?.Tag as TextBox;
if (textBox == null)
{
    // что-то пошло не так
}
```

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Добавил комментарии и код с предосторожностями.

Comment: Так намного понятнее и легче разобраться. Спасибо за полный ответ

Comment: @DenisBubnov: И вам спасибо, без вашей подсказки ответ был бы хуже.